# Why inconsistent regular expression "\bpattern\b" behavior in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python 3 to demonstrate. There is an example string:

a = "learning is learn and elearn"

s = "@wen is @ and wen@"

I want to do exact match of "learn" and "@", i.e., not extracting learning (or @wen) or elearn (or wen@). Therefore, I should get 'learn' and '@'.

```
re.findall(r'\blearn\b', a) # works
['learn']

or

re.sub(r'\blearn\b', 'z', a) # works
'learning is z and elearn'


re.findall(r'\b@\b', s) # not working
[]

or

re.sub(r'\b@\b', 'z', s) # not working
'@wen is @ and wen@'
```

Comment: Your example is returning `['learn', 'learn']` for me on Python 3.5.0

Comment: Can't reproduce your output.

Comment: Sorry, I was using a bad example. I first encountered the problem with string 's' and then wrote an example with string 'a'.

Comment: @wen: The accepted answer is just an explanation, it does not provide a solution. Are you interested how to use both `@` and `learn` as part of a pattern to search for *whole words*?

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `\b` Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character. Note that formally, `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning/end of the string

In your example, `@` is a nonalphanumeric (and non-underscore) character surrounded by other nonalphanumeric characters.  Because there are no word characters, there is no word boundary, so `\b` will not match.